# How can I change an HTML5 div element parameter that is not in the standard namespace?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `div` with a parameter set in the format `ns:name` that I need to manipulate through javascript. (I'm assuming that the part before the colon is a namespace - please correct me if I'm wrong)

So with:

```
<div id="myElement" namespace:name="some value">
```

With JavaScript I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
document.getElementById('myElement').namespace:name = "a new value";
```

I know that's not correct, but is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attribute namespacing is an XML feature only, for the most part. Why not this?

```
document.getElementById('myElement').setAttribute('namespace:name', 'a new value');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

Comment: Perfect! I expected setAttribute to trip up in the same way but I guess it was the colon tripping up the syntax  in my example.

Comment: Additional info: I was looking into this specifically for the AddThis service. After this answer was posted I found the following which is useful as it turns out that just setting the `div`'s attribute doesn't affect the AddThis buttons as I'd hoped: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17992171/change-the-addthis-attribute-addthisurl-and-send-the-new-url-instead-of-the-l

Comment: Yeah, that's the case with almost any plugin. You can't change them after load unless you use a dedicated api.